# Problems broadcasting messages with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to output a message of 'XYZ is typing' whenever a user begins typing but I can't seem to fix my code. I feel as if the 'socket.broadcast.emit' in the App.JS of my code is the issue but I am not sure. If possible can somebody point me in the right direction to helping me fix my chat app. Thanks in advance!

Index.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Chit Chat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
 </head>
  <body>

   <ul id="messages"></ul>
   <div id="typing"></div>

   <form action="">
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" />
    <input id="message-box" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder="Type Message" />
    <button id="button">Send</button>
   </form>


 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/scripts.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

App.JS (Server)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.listen(port, function(){
 console.log('listening on ' + port);
});

// Socket.io
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
 // when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
 socket.on('new message', function(data) {
  // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
  io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
 });
// when the client emits 'typing', we broadcast it to others
 socket.on('typing', function(data){
  socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
 });
});
```

Scripts.JS

```
console.log('Loaded');
var socket = io();

$(function (){
 chat();
 emitEvents();
 isTyping();
});

function chat() {
 $('form').submit(function(e){
  var message = {
  username: $('#username').val(),
  message: $('#message-box').val()
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('new message', message);
   $('#message-box').val('');
  });
}

function isTyping() {
 $('#message-box').keypress(function() {
  socket.emit('typing', $('#username').val());
 });
}

function emitEvents() {
 socket.on('typing', function(data){
  console.log(data);
  $('#typing').append($('<p>').text(data + 'is typing'));
 });
 socket.on('new message', function(data){
  $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(data.username + ': ' + 
  data.message));
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it's working. I have created a [live example](https://repl.it/@user0/BrokenVengefulMedian).

I made 2 modifications in `scripts.js`, so the typing message will appear only once during the typing.

```
function emitEvents() {
    socket.on('typing', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#typing').html($('<p>').text(data + ' is typing')); // update
    });
    socket.on('new message', function(data){
        $('#typing').html($('<p>').text('')); // update
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(data.username + ': ' + data.message));
    });
}
```

The code `socket.broadcast.emit` means sending to all clients except sender.

Check out the [Socket.IO cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/).

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I don't even see my console.log in the browser when I run my code. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Have you checked my "live example"?

Comment: Yes I have. I don't see the typing feature working there either.

Comment: Run the example and open the https://BrokenVengefulMedian--user0.repl.co link in two windows

Comment: Ahh yes I see it. Thank you very much!